# Obtaining a value from a ListView that was populated with a Linq to SQL query

Tags: c#, linq, xaml, listview, linq-to-sql

I am populating a `ListView` from a Linq to SQL query list with this:

```
    private void loademployeelist()
    {
        dbml.hrdbDataContext listpeople = new dbml.hrdbDataContext();
        var q = from p in listpeople.EmpIDs
                join pi in listpeople.EmpBasicFiles on p.EmpID1 equals pi.EBF_EmpID
                where pi.EBF_Active == activeornot
                orderby p.LastName
                select new classes.Employeeselected() { FirstName = p.FirstName, LastName = p.LastName, empid=p.EmpID1};

        foreach (var item in q)
        {
            lb_active_employee_names.Items.Add(new { LastName = item.LastName, FirstName = item.FirstName, empid = item.empid });
        }
    }
```

The problem is that I just want the selected value to be the `empid`. I have looked everywhere and can't find a way to get that value. The code to get the value is this:

```
    private void lb_active_employee_names_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ListViewItem empsel = (ListViewItem)lb_active_employee_names.SelectedItem;
        string test = empsel.GetType().ToString();
        MessageBox.Show(test);
      }
```

I keep getting an error when running the program after I select it. I tried looking up the error, but I am getting lost into this vast wilderness. I think I conceptually understand what is going on, but I don't know how to fix it. I am still very new to C#/Visual Studio.

Here is the error:

`An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in 6DegreesGateway.exe but was not handled in user code`

`Additional information: Unable to cast object of type '<>f__AnonymousType103[System.String,System.String,System.Decimal]' to type 'System.Windows.Controls.ListViewItem'.`

My XAML looks like this:

```
        <ListView x:Name="lb_active_employee_names" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="135" Margin="10,148,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="365" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Loaded="listBox_Loaded" SelectionChanged="lb_active_employee_names_SelectionChanged" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=empid}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Last Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding LastName}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="First Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FirstName}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Employee ID" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding empid}" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

I tried reviewing what others have done, Binding or creating a class etc. But I am just getting more and more confused.

Comment: What do you mean by 'I just want the selected value to be the empid'?  What are you trying to do with the 'empid'?

Comment: Take a look at this similar question.  I think the answer will help.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15091400/get-single-listview-selecteditem

Comment: @JasonBoyd I will be running another query from empid on another table.

Comment: @RudyTheHunter I did look at that site, but it did not work for me. I think I figured out my own solution. I will post it below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code I used when adding the items to the listbox changed the type to anonymous.

```
foreach (var item in q)
    {
        lb_active_employee_names.Items.Add(new { LastName = item.LastName,     FirstName = item.FirstName, empid = item.empid });
    }
```

Instead of that I changed it to this:

```
        foreach (var item in q)
        {
            lb_active_employee_names.Items.Add(item);
        }
```

This way, all of the items in the list, including empid retained their type  (at least this is what I think happened). In any case, I can get the data I need (empid) from that with this line of code:

```
        var empsel = (classes.Employeeselected)lb_active_employee_names.SelectedItem;
        empIdSelected = empsel.empid;
```

And then I can run further queries with that code on other tables.

It's not pretty and I am sure there is a better way to do this.