# select item from listbox and pass it as query to other form

Tags: c#, sql, listview

I have a winforms app in C# in with a user is prompted to select from a range of items, the items are displayed in a `listview` with the `checkboxes` set to true.
After the user selects one item i want the description and a value from an SQL database to be displayed in another form, in 2 textboxes. 
Is there a way to accomplish this?
I think it would be something like:

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        If(listView1.SelectedItems = ??); 
        {
            "select[descri] + '  ' + [compo] from vidros" 
             pass it to form "build" in textbox "desc2"           
            "select valu from vidros" 
             pass it to form "build" in textbox "tt"
             this.close();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please select an item!", "Warning!");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

it is possible. And all the answers are here on StackOverflow:

> After the user selects one item

[Get single listView SelectedItem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15091400/get-single-listview-selecteditem)

> "select[descri] + '  ' + [compo] from vidros"

[How to retrieve data from a SQL Server database in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14171794/how-to-retrieve-data-from-a-sql-server-database-in-c)

> pass it to form "build" in textbox "desc2"

[Send values from one form to another form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559770/send-values-from-one-form-to-another-form)

I wish you success constructing all this information into working code :)

Comment: Thanks, 
ill surely try :)